# Xperido Need steps for nested loop with condtion

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xperido

Using Xperido with CRM , in a way i need to bind data to table

for eg. Product with price list for yearly , Monthly

1. Product Loop
2. Pricelist loop

so i have to loop these 2 and match it and find the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XperiDo has user guide documentation describing how to setup a loop of data [here](http://support.xperido.com/display/tempdes/Loops), I suggest you start there as its a bit too long to reproduce here.

> Loops are one of the basic functions of the XperiDo add-in. With
>   loops, you have the possibility to map a set of recurring items in a
>   list. You can use loops when you have multiple items you want to show,
>   such as a list of contacts, products or services.
>
> Looping in XperiDo is done by following these steps:
>
> - Select the zone to loop over.
> - Select the recurring field in your    dataset.
> - Finalize the loop.
>
> You can then further tweak the loop's settings.